# output is not as desired

Tags: c, linux

```
  // I have used all the header files 
    // code for comparing the directory has matching .recon file  
    // if yes i am printing match found

int main ()
{
    DIR *dp = NULL;
    char *dir = "/home/sv5071184/sample";
    struct dirent *entry;
    struct stat statbuf;    
    char y[20];          
    y[19] = '\0';
    dp = opendir (dir);
    if(dir == NULL)
        return -1;

    while((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        lstat(entry->d_name,&statbuf);
        if(S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)) {
            /* Found a directory, but ignore . and .. */
            if(strcmp(".",entry->d_name) == 0 ||
                strcmp("..",entry->d_name) == 0)
                continue;
            strncpy(y,"111111111",9);
            strncpy ((char *)&y[9], ".", 1);
            strncpy ((char *)&y[10], "000", 3);
            strncpy ((char *)&y[13], ".recon", 6);
            if(strcmp(entry->d_name ,y) == 0)
            {
                printf("match found\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" match not found\n");

            }
        }
    }
    printf ( " The value of y is  %s\n", y );
    closedir(dp);
    return 0;
}
```

I have compiled and executed successfully. but match not found is printing five times before printing match found . please help

Comment: Where does the segmentation fault occur?

Comment: "Segmentation fault" means that you tried to access memory that you do not have access to.

Comment: Instead of using `strncpy` you could use `strcpy(y,"111111111");` and then `strcat(y, ...)` or even simpler `strcpy(y, "111111111.000.recon")`. But even this is still complicated. It leave it as an exercice for the reader to simplify it even more.

Comment: @michael: i have removed memcpy and no errors seen. but is not as desired. i have 111111111.000.recon file in sample directory. but it is going to else condition five times. actually it should go to match found bcoz .recon file is present in sample directory.

Comment: @sandy put some printfs in your code and you'll see what's going on. And why don't you just put `if(strcmp(entry->d_name ,"111111111.000.recon") == 0)`. Your `strncpy` stuff is far too complicated. And furthermore, if you just want to check if the file `111111111.000.recon ` exists, why don't you simply use `stat` ?

Comment: i figured this out by putting printf statements. actually i will have structure member for 9 digit meter and 3 digit component id. i have hardcoded them for better understanding. thanks

Comment: looks to me like there were other files found before the one your looking for.  A strong indication that the code is working correctly.

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
(void) memcpy (y, 0x00, sizeof(y));
```

This means you want top copy `sizeof(y)` bytes to `y` reading from address `0`, which will of course segfault.

You want this:

```
char y[20] = {0};
```

or

```
memset(y, 0x00, sizeof(y));
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here 
`(void) memcpy (y, 0x00, sizeof(y));`
You are giving source pointer for memcpy() as zero. You are using wrong function for setting zero's in buffer y. You should use `memset()` instead of `memcpy()`

Wrong:`(void) memcpy (y, 0x00, sizeof(y));`

Correct: `memset(y, 0x00, sizeof(y));`